# How does lookup work?

Tags: java, netbeans, openide

I have BeanTreeView, and some nodes in it. Every node has constructor

```
public class ProjectNode extends AbstractNode {

public ProjectNode(MainProject obj, DiagramsChildren childrens) {
    super (new ProjectsChildren(), Lookups.singleton(obj));
    setDisplayName ( obj.getName());

}
```

I set Rootnode as a root for tree in ExplorerTopComponent as this:

```
private final ExplorerManager mgr = new ExplorerManager();

public ExplorerTopComponent() {
    associateLookup (ExplorerUtils.createLookup(mgr, getActionMap()));
    mgr.setRootContext(new RootNode());
}
```

And now, how I can get MainProject obj from some node? I need to get it in another class.

Answer (score 1):

[Hi badgirl/Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504560/what-does-this-code-mean) ;-)

To answer the title of your question (nothing about netbeans internals):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504560/what-does-this-code-mean) answers a little bit of your question [what the lookup is](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/ServiceLocator.html): retrieving one or more implementation to the provided key which is normally an interface.

Then Joseph asked: 'which simple pattern can replace this anti pattern?'.
You can't replace the lookup pattern in the NetBeans Platform but to answer his question: I would use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead of lookup in my app via hand wiring, guice, pico container or even spring.
The nice thing about such a library is that you configure just the dependencies and retrieve properly configured instances from the container. See [this nice picture](http://www.picocontainer.org/introduction.html) to get a feeling for this.
(The most dependency injection tools allow also lifecycle management.)

To give an example for dependency injection via hand-wiring assume the following class:

```
class Path {
    List edges = new ArrayList();
    public void setEdges(List e) {
     edges = e;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily switch the ArrayList implementation with a LinkedList:

```
p = new Path();
p.setEdges(new LinkedList());
```

With the lookup concept this is not as easy (but I am not sure):

```
class Path {
  List edges = Lookup.create(List.class);
}
```

Now the usage with the linked list replacement is straight forward:

```
Lookup.set(List.class, LinkedList.class);
p = new Path();
```

but the problem is: How would you use lookup if you have several different classes which needs a List implementation?

you implement your lookup depending on the class which uses it:

```
class Path {
  List edges = Lookup.get(Path.class).create(List.class);
}
```

But to be honest: I prefer the simple dependency injection way. Read [this introduction](http://www.picocontainer.org/inversion-of-control.html) where they also compared lookup and dependency injection (constructor + setter injection).

For more information read [this interesting article from martin fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) which describes service locators (lookup) and inversion of control (dependency injection). Read here about the [history of dependency injection](http://www.picocontainer.org/inversion-of-control-history.html).